# Reaction of unsaturated lactone and alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, reactivity

[image]

[Image source](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/80/14/40/faa149274f8d5f/US3117156.pdf)

I found this equation to turn this compound into an ketoester but I am unsure of the reaction mechanism.

I postulate that the **alcohol** attacks the **carboxyl carbon**, the O becomes formally negative. It reforms the double bond and the **leaving is the O** in the ring which takes the electrons in the bond.

Here my thought differs from the image (gotten from one of the United States Patent Office Patents). I thought the end product would be an ester OHCCCCOOR. Alcohol then alkene and at the end an ester but the picture shows a ketone and no alcohol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that the alcohol atacks the carbonyl then the ring oxygen leaves in a manner analagous to ester transesterification. The intermediate generated is an enol which picks up a proton to for the ketone.

[image]

image from here: [1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Diketene_nucleophilic_reaction.png)

Comment: Oh keto-enol Tautomer. I sometimes have trouble seeing where this can happen. Is there a way to know where this would occur or do you simply have to see many examples and at a certain point you can just see it?

Comment: Most of the time the keto form prevails unless there's extended conjugation. It is worth noting that in this molecule enolisation towards the ester group is the more favoured.